# Error Starting SPIFFS

Tags: esp8266

There is a problem running a simple SPIFFS file system code on different versions of the Arduino IDE, as code shown below. In Arduino IDE version 1.8.4, works fine. No longer version 1.8.9, can not run.
ESP8266
IDE Arduino version 1.8.9

```
#include <FS.h>   

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Init...");
  Serial.println();

  // Always get ERROR on init SPIFFS
  if (!SPIFFS.begin()) {
    Serial.println("SPIFFS.begin error...");
  } else {
    Serial.println("SPIFFS.begin OK!");
  }
}
```

Comment: So you have spiffs turned on in the IDE settings?

Comment: Where can I check that in IDE?

Comment: in Tools menu the "Flash size" option

Comment: OK. It works: Tools -> Flash size 4M (1M SPIFFS). Thanks!!!!